# Postgres: include indicative row values in aggregate query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working in Postgres 9.6. I have a table called `people`:

```
             Table "public.people"
      Column      |       Type        | Modifiers
------------------+-------------------+-----------
 name             | character varying | not null
 address          | character varying |
```

Each person has a unique name, but may share an address.

And a table called `assets`, of the assets owned by the people:

```
           Table "public.assets"
      Column        |         Type         |    Modifiers
--------------------+----------------------+-------------
 id                 | character varying    |
 person_name        | character varying    |
 value              | integer              |
```

The `person_name` field in `assets` is the same identifier as the `name` field in `people`, so the two tables can be joined.

I want to find the **address** that owns the most assets by value. But the difficulty is that I'd also like my results to include some of the names (either one name, or all names).

This is because the addresses on their own don't tell me a lot - it would be much easier to understand the results if they have some names in.

I know how to retrieve the value of the assets owned by each person:

```
SELECT 
  person_name, SUM(value) as total_value
FROM assets
GROUP BY person_name
```

And I know how to join and group this to get the total value by address:

```
SELECT 
  p.address, SUM(a.total_value) FROM people p
JOIN
  (SELECT person_name, SUM(value) as total_value
  FROM assets
  GROUP BY person_name) a
ON 
  a.person_name=p.name
GROUP BY 
  p.address 
ORDER BY total_value DESC;
```

But how can I retrieve some of the names too in the results - either a single name, or the whole lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `name` in an aggregate function, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    p.address, 
    min(name) as name,
    sum(a.total_value) as total_value
...
```

to get the alphabetically first name, or

```
SELECT 
    p.address, 
    array_agg(name) as names,
    sum(a.total_value) as total_value
...
```

to get all names in an array.